# How can you change ./configure to use a specific binary over /usr/bin?

Tags: path, macos, configure, autoconf, bison

Running macOS Catalina 10.15.6.
My question is more related to compilation with GNU tools, so it may be more suited for a different SE site — I'll be happy to close and ask somewhere else if that's the case.

I'm trying to compile software (namely `wine-6.0`) and the compilation requires bison, for which there's already an executable in `/usr/bin`. However, bison needs to be version >3.0 to compile the program and the binary in `/usr/bin` is version 2.7.6. I compiled bison 3.7.6 and I was gonna just move the new bison 3.7 binary into `/usr/bin` but due to the filesystem protection of macOS, I can't just replace `/usr/bin/bison`. I'd have to restart my mac in recovery mode to disable the filesystem lock, but I have something open that can't stop running at the moment.

Using `./configure --enable-win64` gives the following error:

```
checking for bison... bison
checking whether bison is recent enough... no
configure: error: Your bison version is too old. Please install bison version 3.0 or newer.
```

To fix it, I thought modifying `PATH` would work; I moved the bison 3.7.6 binary to `/usr/local/bin/bison` and did `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` before `./configure` but it doesn't work; it still just errors about not having bison >3.0 (the same error as before I tried to mess with bison):

```
checking for bison... bison
checking whether bison is recent enough... no
configure: error: Your bison version is too old. Please install bison version 3.0 or newer.
```

The weird thing is, just trying to run bison uses the right binary.

```
$ bison -V
bison (GNU Bison) 3.7.6
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.
...

$ which bison
/usr/local/bin/bison
```

I also tried messing with the `configure.ac` file a little, but the problem is I don't really know what I'm doing there. Editing the config file and rerunning `autoconf` and using `./configure` then still doesn't work.
Ultimately, my question is: how do I ensure `./configure` uses the correct bison binary?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that the `bison` install was bad.

I compiled bison from source with `configure --prefix=/usr/local` instead of letting brew decide where to put everything and then made sure PATH was correct when using `configure` to gen the makefile for the wine compilation, and it worked.

The problem arose from the wine configure script just checking the exit code of running Bison on an empty file to verify the version. Because bison was failing due to a broken install, it was giving the error exit code, causing the configure script to believe bison was an insufficient version.